# Input array with unknown variable column size

Tags: c

I have to solve the following problem:

Raghav is an online shopper. He wants to order some products. But before he orders the products he wants to compare it with the other merchants. Each row specifies a product but the limitation of comparing the prices are only with maximum of three merchants. Find the minimum in each row and add the price and display.

**Assume the limit to buy a product is 10. 
Assume the number of merchant for each product may vary from 1 to 3.**

[image]

#### Test cases

**Input 1**

```
Enter the number of products:
3
Enter the price per product:
110 102 100
250 200 312
412 450 475
```

**Output 1**

```
The minimum cost of each product is as follows
100
200
412
Total amount you need to pay Rs.712
```

**Input 2**

```
Enter the number of products:
13
```

**Output 2**

```
You are allowed to buy maximum of 10 products
```

**Input 3**

```
Enter the number of products:
3
Enter the price per product
100 250
500 300
450 350
```

**Output 3**

```
The minimum cost of each product is as follows
100
300
350
Total amount you need to pay Rs.750
```

***This is my code:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NN 31

int main()
{
int n;
printf("Enter the number of products:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

if (n>10)
{ 
 printf("You are allowed to buy maximum of 10 products"); return 0;
}

printf("Enter the price per product:\n");

//Storing  the input in a 2D string first

char **str=malloc((n)*sizeof(char *));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    str[i]=malloc(NN);
}

scanf("\n");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fgets(str[i],NN,stdin);
}

int **arr=(int **)calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    arr[i]=(int *)calloc(3,sizeof(int));

//Conversion of 2D string to 2D integer array

int max;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int num, j = 0, len;
    max=j;
while ( sscanf( str[i], "%d%n", &num, &len) == 1 ) 
{
    arr[i][j]=num;
    str[i] += len;    
    j++;
    if(j>max) max=j;        //find the column size of 2D array   
}
}

//Calculation of minimum possible cost
int *min,amount=0;
 min=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(min));

printf("The minimum cost of each product is as follows:\n");

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    min[i]=arr[i][0];
    for(int j=1;j<max;j++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j]<min[i])
        {
            min[i]=arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",min[i]);
    amount=amount+min[i];
    }
 printf("Total amount you need to pay Rs.%d",amount);
 free(min);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    free(str[i]);
    free(arr[i]);
}
free(str);
free(arr);
return 0;
}
```

This code works fine if the input is provided as shown above (I read each row separately and terminate the row when \n is encountered).

***But how to handle the cost inputs if they are provided as follows:***

**Input 4**

```
Enter the number of products:
3
Enter the price per product
100
250
500
300
450
350
```

Again, the column size can vary between 1 to 3 and the user does not specify the column size.

I need help regarding how to stop the array input as and when the user stops. He/She may enter 3 or 6 or 9 prices for 3 products(n=3).

Comment: Minor:  allocation size and `fgets()` size can be the same `#define NN 31  ...   str[i]=malloc(NN); ...  fgets(str[i],NN,stdin);` also no need for all that casting like `(char *)` cast.

Comment: @chux edited. Thanks.

Comment: Prepare the maximum number. E.g `int prices[10 * 3];`

Comment: The last case is confusing.  number of products is 3, so why 6 lines of prices?  Should not the 4th line onward be considered errors?

Comment: @chux For each product, there **can** be 1 to 3 prices. If there are 2 merchants for each product, there will be 6 prices. And the user may enter all the prices serially like this.

Comment: As it stands, there isn't any basis for handling the last set of data very well.  One possibility is to treat each line as one entry; stop when you reach 3 lines of 1 entry per line.  Report that 300, 450, and 350 are too many products to order,  Without better instructions on what to do, you're hosed.  (An alternative would be to read 3 lines as the entries for the first product, the next 3 as the entries for the second product, and prompt for more data or object to incomplete data if you get EOF after that.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY okay, but my problem is how to stop the array input/string input after the user enters as many prices he wants.

Comment: Detecting termination in the case of input exceeding the default number, I guess if it is not instructed by the user it will be EOF.

Comment: @AritraDasgupta scanf("%[\n]",str); it stops taking input when "\n" is encountered. Hope it helps.

Comment: For the last case, until line **7**, code does not know if 3 more lines of data are expected.

Comment: Insist that the prices for one product are on one line of input, as in the first examples.  You have no way to know how to piece together 6 lines when there are 3 items on order.

Comment: @Vimal `scanf("%[\n]",str);` does _not_ stop taking input when "\n" is entered.  It wait for more `'\n'`.  Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` is the [road to perdition](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/perdition).

Comment: I think the best option for you right now is to wait for EOF. Keep doing `scanf` in a loop. It will not return 1 when the input stream ends.

Comment: your are loosing `str[i]` here ` str[i] += len;` the free cannot work

Comment: IMO, dis-allow case 4.  After the 3rd line is entered, give the result just like in case 3

Comment: http://ideone.com/Ncd1oa this code might help..

Comment: Thanks. checking for EOF worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the user input you can read all lines the user enters (up to 9 for the last case) and if the user has entered more then n lines, check for each line after, if the line is empty. If line is empty the user has completed their input.

Comment: So in cases 2,3, user now needs to do something more to get the results.

Comment: @chux updated my answer, if >n lines check for empty line.

Comment: Thanks. This worked:                                                              
    `int i=0;  while(i<n1&&scanf("%d",&a[i])==1) i++;`

Answer (score 0):

here a solution

Add a loop to enter several value,
break the loop when the user set number of product to 0.

Fix free of `str[i]`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NN 31

int main() 
{       
    int n;  
    while (42) {
        printf("Enter the number of products, 0 to quit:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if (n > 10)
        {
            printf("You are allowed to buy maximum of 10 products");
            continue;
        } else if (n == 0) {
            printf("Bye");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Enter the price per product:\n");

        //Storing  the input in a 2D string first

        char **str=malloc((n)*sizeof(char *));
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            str[i] = malloc(NN);
        }

        scanf("\n"); 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            fgets(str[i], NN, stdin);
        }

        int **arr= (int **)calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = (int *)calloc(3,sizeof(int));

        //Conversion of 2D string to 2D integer array

        int max;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {       
            int num, j = 0, len;
            char *p = str[i];
            max=j;
            while ( sscanf(p, "%d%n", &num, &len) == 1 )
            {
                arr[i][j]=num;
                p += len;
                j++;
                if(j>max) max=j;        //find the column size of 2D array
            }
        }

        //Calculation of minimum possible cost
        int *min,amount=0;
        min=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(min));

        printf("The minimum cost of each product is as follows:\n");
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {       
            min[i]=arr[i][0];
            for(int j=1;j<max;j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j]<min[i])
                {
                    min[i]=arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            printf("%d\n",min[i]);
            amount=amount+min[i];
        }
        printf("Total amount you need to pay Rs.%d\n",amount);
        free(min);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            free(str[i]);
            free(arr[i]);
        }
        free(str);
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't change the input from test case, as it will be evaluated as incorrect.

Comment: What to you expect as output for your input 4 ?

Comment: The input of 6 prices values is interpreted as a 3 x 2 matrix with 2 prices for each of the 3 products. The output is sum of the minimum in each row.

Comment: How you detect the user has finished to give input ? perhaps he will give 9 prices, 3 prices for 3 products ?

Comment: I used this: `int i=0; n1=3*n; while(i<n1&&scanf("%d",&a[i])==1) i++;`

Comment: This doesn't work if the user is running the program, but this is working when the test cases are fixed and the program is being evaluated by test cases as there will be EOF or the scanf return value becomes 0.                    Otherwise, the user has to provide some input regarding columnsize.